# What does a semicolon after function inside function mean?

Tags: c++

I saw an answer for a c++ challenge that had you copy a certain part of a string x times.

```
std::string repeatString(int xTimes)
{
   repeatString;(3); //What's happening here?
}
```

He seemed to have solved the challenge with this code and I'm guessing he solved it the wrong way but I'm still unsure what's happening.

original challenge:
https://edabit.com/challenge/vxpP4nnDhRr2Yc3Lo

original answer by Marcus_2008

Comment: its a typo. The function also does not return a string, hence calling it invokes undefined behavior

Comment: The program is ill-formed here. These body just contains two independent expressions, but the function doesn't return anything while `std::string` is expected

Comment: Yes it doesn't make any sense. Throw it away and write your own solution.

Comment: Bad code; does not return a value.

Comment: That's only *one* of the many problems with so-called "challenge", "competition" or "judging" sites: Many code examples on them are really bad. Sometimes even invalid. Don't use such sites to learn *anything* (unless all you want to learn are bad habits and bad code).

Comment: Some useful information in the compiler warnings if you turn them up to a reasonable level. Eg:  https://godbolt.org/z/K8xWfssor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`repeatString;` is an expression that does nothing useful. Same for `(3);`. Its the same as `3;` and does literally nothing. After removing that unnecessary fluff, the function is

```
std::string repeatString(int) {
    //What's happening here? 
    // - nothing at all
}
```

And this, not only does it not repeat a string, but it invokes undefined behavior when called, because it is declared to return a `std::string` but does not.

Even changing the line to `repeatString(3);` would leave us with the same issue while `return repeatString(3);`  would result in infinite recursion.

It is not possible that this code solves the task. You must have misunderstood something, or the real code looks different.

Comment: `repeatString(3);` would be an infinite recursion even without return.